# XCode 4.2.1 @autoreleasepool not working

Tags: xcode, nsautoreleasepool

I have a Console application with Xcode 4.2.1 and the keyword @autolreleasepool is not compiling:
[image: Compiler error]
The compiler seems to be set properly for my Console application:
[image: Project build settings]
Do you have any suggestion? I want to understand why the new keyword doesn't work if I have Xcode 4.2.1, I know how to write the autoreleasepool using the old syntax.

**UPDATE**

This is code that does not compile

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool{

        NSMutableArray *array;
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            NSNumber *newNumber =
            [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:(i * 3)];
            [array addObject:newNumber];
        }
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            NSNumber *numberToPrint = [array objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"The number at index %d is %@",  i, numberToPrint);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the line above. Have you missed a terminator, or does something look wrong? This message sometimes pops up because it's interpreting the current line as part of the line above.

Comment: I've just run that, and it compiles and runs just fine on my machine.

Comment: @Abizern can you please tell me what is the setting of your main.c file? I have File type: default - C source

Comment: I found the issue!
Instead of creating a command line project with a Type = "Foundation" I used Type = "Core Foundation". I changed that to "Foundation" and now it compiles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue!
Instead of creating a command line project with a Type = "Foundation" I used Type = "Core Foundation". I changed that to "Foundation" and now it compiles!

Answer (score 0):

Is ARC enable for this file? Check both the project / target level settings and the individual compiler flags for the file.

Comment: Yes it does, both file and project are configured using ARC, i do not understand why it does not compile

Comment: Then it might help to show a slightly larger snippet of code - the error might be before the @autoreleasepool statement.

Comment: I have a Cocoa app and if I use the @autoreleasepool keyword it works perfectly, it also popups from the intellisense, in this Console application, in the .c file, it doesn't. ???

Comment: ARC is not required for `@autoreleasepool`, just the LLVM Compiler 3.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950583/autoreleasepool-without-arc

Comment: Cool! Learn something everyday