# What is the difference between NSAutoreleasePool and @autoreleasepool block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsautoreleasepool

I want to know what are the differences between NSAutoreleasePool and @autoreleasepool block.I have gone through a number of questions but didn't get any satisfying answer.Till now I came to know that in ARC we can't use NSAutoreleasePool and @autoreleasepool block can be used in both `ARC enabled and disabled` case.So in what respect they are different internally to behave in that way.

Is it necessary to release the objects in an arc disabled environment even though we are using **NSAutoreleasePool** or @autoreleasepool block or they will do it automatically?Also,if ARC release memory automatically then why we use **@autoreleasepool** block.Please give me a brief overview with example.

Comment: From the docs apple says that if you use arc you cannot use NSAutoreleasePool you have to use @autoreleasepool. Look further into https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I saw this in the above link:  -Important: If you use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), you cannot use autorelease pools directly. Instead, you use @autoreleasepool blocks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Xcode 4.2 use @autoreleasepool in main.m instead of NSAutoreleasePool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714875/why-does-xcode-4-2-use-autoreleasepool-in-main-m-instead-of-nsautoreleasepool)

Comment: @leo...The difference the link gave I have already mentioned in my question.I wanted to know that is it the only difference or there are others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One difference you mentioned :

> In ARC we can't use NSAutoreleasePool and @autoreleasepool block can
>   be used in both ARC enabled and disabled case.

But for yours this statement :

> Also,if ARC release memory automatically then why we use
>   @autoreleasepool block

ARC doesn't release memory automatically! It's a compile time feature where every object is sent an `autorelease` and it goes to the local pool. Once its lifetime and scope are over, the pool OS releases itself resulting in the release of all objects.

You may refer this blog [Are @autoreleasepool Blocks More Efficient?](https://web.archive.org/web/20130822075935/http://www.longyiqi.com/blog/programming-languages/2011/11/23/are-autoreleasepool-blocks-more-efficient)

> Is it necessary to release the objects in an arc disabled environment
>   even though we are using NSAutoreleasePool or @autoreleasepool block
>   or they will do it automatically?

**Yes** you need to release the objects. As per definition of `(@/NS)autoreleasepool`, it doesn't handle your object retain counts but it is used only for the following :

> Autorelease pool blocks provide a mechanism whereby you can relinquish
>   ownership of an object, but avoid the possibility of it being
>   deallocated immediately (such as when you return an object from a
>   method).

Comment: Thanks Anoop for the answer.One more question is there i.e. Is it necessary to release the objects in an arc disabled environment even though we are using NSAutoreleasePool or @autoreleasepool block or they will do it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

The `NSAutoreleasePool` class is used to support Cocoa’s reference-counted memory management system. An autorelease pool stores objects that are sent a `release` message when the pool itself is drained.

Also,  If you use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), you cannot use autorelease pools directly. Instead, you use `@autoreleasepool` blocks. For example, in place of:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// Code benefitting from a local autorelease pool.
[pool release];
```

You would write:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // Code benefitting from a local autorelease pool.
}
```

`@autoreleasepool` blocks are more efficient than using an instance of `NSAutoreleasePool` directly; you can also use them even if you do not use ARC.

You can refer the Apple document for more detail:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html