# @autoreleasepool in ios 5

Tags: ios5

Why we use  @autoreleasepool in ios 5?

My point is ios 5 has no autorelease,release,retain.but we use  @autoreleasepool in main class. pls give me a solution.

What is the use of autoreleasepool inside a method?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) this means **you** are not allowed to use autorelease, release and retain **but** the Compiler automatically includes these Statements at the correct Position. ARC is not a Runtime feature, but a compiler feature. that's why you nonetheless need the @autoreleasepool.

see also:
[@autoreleasepool without ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950583/autoreleasepool-without-arc)