# objectiveC autorelease issue, what is wrong with code?

Tags: objective-c

New to objective-C,

```
#import <objc/objc.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Test:NSObject
{
  int x,y, abc;
  NSString *v1, *v2;
}
@property int x , y, abc;
-(void) print;

@end

@implementation Test
@synthesize x,y, abc;
-(void) print
{
 NSLog (@"v1 and v2 values %i, %i ", v1, v2);
}

@end

int main ( int argc, char **argv)

{
  Test *t = [[Test alloc] init];
  /* Synthesized Set Method */
  [t setX:100];
  [t setY:200];
 /* Synthesized Get Method */
  NSLog (@"Retrieving Values %i, %i ",[t x], [t y]);

 /* another Way to retrieve the throuhg KVC Model */
 NSLog (@" KVC Retrieveal  %i ", [t valueForKey:@"x"]);
```

}

I did not get compile time error, but run time error i got :

```
2012-04-11 16:25:08.470 testpgm[22237] Retrieving Values 100, 200 
2012-04-11 16:25:08.513 testpgm[22237] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8e78ca0) of class NSMethodSignature in thread <NSThread: 0x8e23a08>
2012-04-11 16:25:08.514 testpgm[22237] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8e94610) of class NSIntNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x8e23a08>
2012-04-11 16:25:08.514 testpgm[22237]  KVC Retrieveal  149505552
```

Looks like it is something to do with memory issue. some one point out the issue ?

**NOTE:** With all your inputs, i could resolve the autorelease issue, but still

```
NSLog (@" KVC Retrieveal  %i ", [t valueForKey:@"x"]);
```

does not print the proper value but the garbage. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Your revised question has nothing to do with your original question. But the answer is that the format string "%i" specifies an integer while `valueForKey:` returns an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are in the run loop of an application, there is a default autorelease pool created for you. However, when you are running with your own `main`, you need to create an autorelease pool manually at the top of your `main`, and drain it periodically.

```
NSAutoreleasePool *myPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// Your code that uses autorelease...
[myPool drain];
```

If you are compiling with the new LLVM compiler, use the new `@autoreleasepool` feature instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using GNUStep to compile in ubuntu and running.

Comment: `@autoreleasepool` can be used in all Objective-C modes, not only ARC

Comment: Well, i added as you suggested, now i dont get the runtime error , but NSLog (@" KVC Retrieveal  %i ", [t valueForKey:@"x"]);, does not print x value why ?

Comment: @beryllium You are right, I [found this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7950636/335858) and edited my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The main routine does not create an autorelease pool.

Use one of these methods depending on the version and compiler you are using.

Newer or with ARC:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

    // your code

    }
}
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

     // your code

    [pool drain];
}
```

The code has numerous other problems such as:

```
NSLog (@"v1 and v2 values %i, %i ", v1, v2);
```

which should be

```
NSLog (@"v1 and v2 values %@, %@ ", v1, v2);
```

%@ is used to print objects, %i for integers.

The line:

```
NSLog (@" KVC Retrieveal  %i ", [t valueForKey:@"x"]);
```

is interesting because valueForKey returns an object (in this case an `NSNumber`) so the correct statement is:

```
NSLog (@" KVC Retrieveal  %@ ", [t valueForKey:@"x"]);
```

Running the program with these corrections produces:

```
Retrieving Values 100, 200 
KVC Retrieveal  100
```

Answer (score 1):

`main` function must have an autorelease pool.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        // you code

        return ...;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Regarding your second part of question. `valueForKey` returns `id`, cast it to `int`

```
NSLog (@" KVC Retrieveal  %i ", [[t valueForKey:@"x"] intValue]);
```

Comment: That is not a cast, it is a method call on the returned object returning an integer.

Comment: Yes, I say it for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main ( int argc, char **argv)

{
 NSAutoreleasePool *myPool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
  Test *t = [[Test alloc] init];
  /* Synthesized Set Method */
  [t setX:100];
  [t setY:200];
 /* Synthesized Get Method */
  NSLog (@"Retrieving Values %i, %i ",[t x], [t y]);

 /* another Way to retrieve the throuhg KVC Model */
 NSLog (@" KVC Retrieveal  %i ", [t valueForKey:@"x"]);

 [pool drain];
}
```

may be it will work