# autoreleased with no pool in place - NO new thread is started

Tags: ios, ios5, memory-leaks, static, nsautoreleasepool

> objc[23601]: Object 0x12b090f0 of class __NSCFSet autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug

Why would the following code section print the leak error above?

```
+ (BOOL)getSkipFlag
{

    NSUserDefaults* defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ( ![defs objectForKey:_BOOK_ID] )
    {
        [defs setObject:@"yyyy" forKey:_BOOK_ID];

        [defs synchronize];
    }

    if ( ![[defs objectForKey:_BOOK_ID] isEqualToString:@"xxxx"] )
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return skipFlag;
}
```

usage

```
if ( ![ClassXYZ getSkipFlag] )
....
```

I don't use a new thread so I should not have a new autorelease pool set up.

Note: `NSString *temp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:_CONFIG_PLIST ofType:@"plist"];` - would print the same error
I am using iOS 5.1

Thanks for any insight.

UPDATE:
ClassXYZ.m
...
static BOOL skipFlag = NO;

setter:
    + (void)setSkipFlag:(BOOL)boolValue
    {
        skipFlag = boolValue;
    }

usage:
[ClassXYZ setSkipFlag:YES];

used in 
static void
convert_uri_to_file_name(struct mg_connection *conn, const char *uri,
        char *buf, size_t buf_len)

Omar you had a good point about where it is used. It turns out if I ClassXYZ's own instance methods for example, it works without errors.

Comment: very nice case :), would please provide more code around if ( ![ClassXYZ getSkipFlag] ) or posting the caller function that prints this

Comment: just out of curiosity, if you put the function call inside an @autorelease does the log goes away?

Comment: well Omar, looks like you just solved my problem. added @autoreleasepool{ ... } and the log disappeared. For some reason I assumed the this will not work for a non-arc project and never bothered trying it. [I should have checked this before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950583/autoreleasepool-without-arc]. So thank a lot, and please add an answer so I can accept yours as the resolution.

Comment: interesting that if I created an autorelease pool and then drained it at the end it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just out of curiosity, if you put the function call inside an `@autorelease` that log should go away

Answer (score 1):

Generally, The autorelease pool for main thread would be created at the first line of `main` function. Anything that runs before `main` function would see that the autorelease pool is absent.

`+load` function is one reason that would cause the leaks, because it runs before `main` function. If that's the case, just consider using `+initialize` instead.

Comment: thanks tia. added +(void)initialize{skipFlag=NO;} but it does not help. I used static BOOL skipFlag; for this case in the .m file.