# Create calendar event from inside my application

Tags: iphone, ios, eventkit

I know that there already are lots of questions and even useful answers concerning this question on the web. I tried to add a calendar event to the iPhone calendar from inside my application. I used this code, which actually worked:

```
EKEventStore *es = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEventEditViewController *controller = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
controller.eventStore = es;
controller.editViewDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

The only thing was that I could not release the calendar controller, which is because I should have said:

```
[Controller release]
```

or something
But my main.m is set to autorelease:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
          return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([...AppDelegate class]));
    }   
}
```

and if I manually release I get an error, do I have to change something in the main.m?

Comment: sure you are not using ARC already?

Comment: Doesn't having `@autoreleasepool` imply that ARC is being used? Correct me if I'm wrong. **edit** I stand corrected. [@autoreleasepool without ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950583/autoreleasepool-without-arc/7950636#7950636)

Comment: How about `[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: I think I actually use ARC then...

Comment: Better thing to change is going to ARC.

Comment: I get an error when I use:

Comment: [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the comments, it might be you are using ARC. In order to check that, go on your project tab, select *Build Settings* and type in the search bar

> Automatic Reference Counting

If it's set to you YES, you don't need to release the object.

**EDIT**

It looks like there have been a misunderstanding regarding the word *release*. Release as you mentioned it (calling *release* on an object) means *to decrease the object reference counter*. 
Dismissing a modal view controller is a complete different thing. In order to do that,
on the **cancel** button delegate method, you have to invoke:

```
[yourViewControllerInstance dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

That's the method you are searching for.

Comment: it is and I did not realease the controller: But when I run my app in the simulator I can't press done or cancel, at leatst nothing happens

Comment: Ahh that you meant with "release": dismissing the modal view controller? Not release the memory object, right?

Answer (score 0):

In your target's build settings, if you see **Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting** then you are using ARC:

[image]

And if you are using ARC then you are not responsible to release object by your self.

I strongly recommend to read more about ARC, you can start from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1), this is the most important thing you should consider if you want to build a real application.

Comment: then search for the world release] and remove it from your code.

Comment: sorry if you misunderstood, I already did but when I run the app in the simulator I can't exit the calendar controller after creating an event

Comment: You need to do this: '[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];'